# How do I ensure Rails controller test post response is JSON, and why is this not the right approach?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, testing, controller, minitest

I have a standard scaffolded blog PostController, and I'm trying to write a simple controller test to test the JSON API. However, instead of a 201 created (in the format.json block), I am getting a 302 redirected, as if the format.html block is being executed. Why, and how should I fix it?

```
# test/api/post_api_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

describe PostsController do
  # reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before :all do
    @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
    Post.delete_all
  end

  describe 'POST /posts' do
    it 'can create a post via api' do
      expected = {
        title: Faker::Name.name,
        body: Faker::Lorem.paragraph,
        published: true
      }
      post_params = {
        post: expected
      }
      request_headers = {
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-type' => 'application/json'
      }

      sign_in users(:editor)
      post :create, post_params, request_headers
      # DEBUG
      # puts "response.body #{response.body} END"
      Post.count.must_equal 1
      Post.last.title.must_equal expected[:title]
      response.status.must_equal 201
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE /posts/:id' do
    it 'deletes a post via JSON' do
      skip
    end
  end

  describe 'PATCH /posts/:id' do
    it 'updates a post via JSON' do
      skip
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
# posts_controller.rb
# blog post controller
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    logger.debug current_user
    @posts = policy_scope(Post)
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @commentable = @post
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save

        current_user.posts << @post
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render status: :created }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, (:published if current_user.editor?))
    end
end
```

and:

```
ruby -I"lib:test" test/controllers/post_api_test.rb                                                                                             
Run options: --seed 5965

# Running:

...FSS

Fabulous run in 0.466405s, 12.8644 runs/s, 21.4406 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
PostsController::POST /posts#test_0001_can create a post via api       [test/controllers/post_api_test.rb:70]:
Expected: 201
Actual: 302

6 runs, 10 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 2 skips

You have skipped tests. Run with --verbose for details.
```

Comment: a gist of the code is available here: https://gist.github.com/ivanoats/0cf98fe694ba06910c6b and the entire project is here: https://github.com/ivanoats/portfolio/tree/api_test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I got to work:

```
request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "application/json"
request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"
post :create, post_params, format: :json
```

kind of hacky, but it works.

Comment: Heh, I just noticed I left off the "Accept" header in my example. Oh well. The most confusing part about this is it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. Maybe a PR for rack-test that allows you to use the more familiar format would be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try `post :create, post_params, as: :json`

Comment: Thanks but sorry, same result. I've also tried `format: :json`

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, rack-test requires the headers to be in a very particular format. Instead of:

```
  request_headers = {
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
  }
```

Try:

```
  request_headers = {
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
  }
```

Comment: thanks for chiming in! unfortunately I still have the issue. I also tried: `post :create, post_params, {format: :json, "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"}`